# When using class_eval in ruby, how to access the constant in the original class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to extend a class using class_eval, and while trying to access the constant from the original class, I got an error saying:

NameError: uninitialized constant HIS_CONSTANT
    from ./my_module.rb:35:in `show_his_constant'
    from (irb):4

I tested with a sample program, and can't make it work. Can someone pls check and see why this is not working? Thanks!

```
module MyModule
  puts "start my module"
  def mytest
    puts "mytest"
  end

  module YourModule
    def yourtest
      puts "yourtest"
    end
  end
end

module MyModule
  module YourModule
    module HisModule
      HIS_CONSTANT = 'THIS_IS_A_CONSTANT'
    end
  end
end

module MyModule
  module YourModule
    class HisClass
      include HisModule
      def show_constant
        puts HIS_CONSTANT
      end
    end
  end
end

MyModule::YourModule::HisClass.class_eval do
  def show_his_constant
    puts HIS_CONSTANT
  end
end
```

BTW, I know this way can work:

```
MyModule::YourModule::HisClass.class_eval do
  def show_his_constant
    puts MyModule::YourModule::HisModule::HIS_CONSTANT
  end
end
```

But I don't want to use namespace to access, since it should already be included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be using ruby 1.8 as your code appears to work as written in 1.9.

In 1.8 the problem seems to be that the constant is bound in the context of where the block is defined (whatever `self` was when you started to write `MyModule::YourModule::HisClass.class_eval`). You can delay the constant binding until `self` has become an instance of `MyModule::YourModule::HisClass` by using [`Module.const_get`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Module.html#method-i-const_get).

```
MyModule::YourModule::HisClass.class_eval do
  def show_his_constant
    puts self.class.const_get(:HIS_CONSTANT)
  end
end

irb 1.8.7> MyModule::YourModule::HisClass.new.show_his_constant
THIS_IS_A_CONSTANT
```

Comment: Thank you! I am glad to learn that it's a limitation from Ruby 1.8 :) This is a nice workaround.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
MyModule::YourModule::HisClass.class_eval do
  def show_his_constant
    puts self::class::HIS_CONSTANT
  end
end
```